# How to use LookUp column?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have one custom SharePoint list. In the list I have 4 columns:

- Store No
- Store Name
- Item No
- Item Name

I want to make one child list in such way that the Item Name and the Store Name columns in the parent list are populated with values from the child list based on the values of the Store No and the Item No columns in the parent list.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a list **Stores** with columns (**Store No** and **Store Name**) and a list **Items** (with columns **Item No** and **Item Name**).

In your parent list you create a column **Store No** with the following settings:

- Column Type: Calculated

[image]

Do the same for **Items**