# Using a Lookup Column (follow up question)

Tags: list, lookup-column, calculated-column

Following up this question on using Lookup columns:
[How to use LookUp column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/184256/how-to-use-lookup-column)

How would you make this work looking up values from a calculated field (Store No) rather than manually inputting the value to lookup on?
E.g.

```
Location    Size Supported      Store No (=[Loc.]&[Size])   Store Name  
   A             1                 A1                         StoreA  
   A             2                 A2                         StoreB  
   A             3                 A3                         StoreC  
   B             1                 B1                         StoreD  
   B             2                 B2                         StoreE  
   B             3                 B3                         StoreF
```

data can be looked up by
**Parent List**

```
Order      Location    Size    Store No (=[Location]&[Size])  
  1           A         2             A2  
  2           B         2             B2  
  3           A         1             A1
```

---

So that that the Parent List becomes;
**Parent List**

```
Order      Location    Size    Store No (=[Loc]&[Size])  Store Name (lookup)
  1           A         2             A2                    Store B
  2           B         2             B2                    Store E
  3           A         1             A1                    Store A
```

---

(Where Store No is a Calculated Column in both the Parent List and Looked up List)
?

Answer (score 0):

Create two Lists

- first will be stores: Like Table1:  Store No, StoreName fields
- second will be like Table3: Order, Item No, Store No (lookup field to the Table1), Store Name (store name will be added when creating LookUp field as additional value)

Follow picture:

1. Select **Lookup**
2. Select **Table1** list
3. Select **Store No**
4. Check **Store Name**

[image]

Comment: If the Store No field in the parent List is a lookup, how is it meant to know what to look for? The Store No. needs to be known in both lists for the parent list to find the right data. What I want to do in the parent list is - knowing the Store No, look that up in the other list to bring in the name of that store.

Comment: Yes, when you creating item in Table3, you will select Store No and the Store Name will be added automatically for the selected Store No. Try it its a 5 min work.

Comment: The Lookup field confuses me, as instead of the usual:  
**look for value "X" in Column "Y" of other table, returning the Column "Z" value from the same row.**   -   it seems to be:   **look in Column "Y" of other table returning the Column Z value from ??Row??**.

Comment: I have tried and I am not surprised that it's not working. How on earth would each row in Table 3 know which Store No to look for in Table 1?

Comment: I think that the misunderstanding is that - I can't manually input the value in the "Store No" column in Table 3 - I need it to use an earlier column in Table 3 for that.

Comment: ok, so there should be used calculated field for the Store Name.

Comment: But it's not possible to create a calculated column that uses columns from a different List

Comment: Oh i see now, probably workflow will be the only OOTB chance how to achieve it.

Comment: havent time now, going try something later.